# BlueOcean not showing input before parallel stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

In a pipeline script of mine, I have the following:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  options {
    skipDefaultCheckout(true)
  }
  stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
      //Checkout steps
    }

    stage('Clean') {
      when {
        expression {
          def result = input(message: 'Clean?', ok: 'Go for it!')
          return true
        }
        beforeAgent true
      }
      parallel {
        stage("Clean Project 1") {
          // Clean steps
        }
        stage("Clean Project 2") {
          // Clean steps
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm expecting there to be a waiting step before the parallel stage "Clean" begins to run however the pipeline ends up looking like this:

[image: Screenshot]

I have even tried to add another step between checkout and clean with just an input as a step but that hasn't worked either. I could put the input st the end of the checkout steps but that is not desired.

Comment: what happens if you won't click ok?

Comment: Nothing, it just waits at the stage which is what I want.

Comment: It happens to me sometimes and I think it is an issue of blueocean UI. What I do is trigger the input in classic Jenkins UI